# Allow requests just within my domain for an specific node endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

What can i do to restrict request to an specific endpoint just within my same domain in node.js (from another node apps under the same domain) ?

It is just for "/test" endpoint, which should not be reachable from outside.

Checking origin header?
Should be node the one which restrict? Or nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not rely on http headers. Everyone can put in http headers whatever he wants.

The better way is to restrict access by IP. And make it configurable in node.js app. For example with env variable: `ALLOW=127.0.0.1 node app.js`

The hard way is compare IP from DNS for host in origin header with remote address of connection.

The simple way is to use access tokens and pass it in `authorization` header.